# How to sort child entities using datastore api

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Here I'm using Datastore API to create, update & retrieve entities.

My use case is, have to get the child and grand child entities of a parent entity.

My entity structure is as follows:

```
 Company
     --> Employee
            --> Address (Multiple Address entities).
```

Here I have `Company` entity key and I need to fetch `Employee` details along with all the `Address` entities configured to the employee.

Example:

```
Company --> Aaa
     Employee --> John 
                  Address --> California
                  Address --> Redwood
     Employee --> Robert
                  Address --> New York
                  Address --> Washington
```

My required result is:

1. Employee entities of John & Robert along with the respective `Address` entities.
2. Employee entities should be sort by name.

My query is as follows:

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

Query query = new Query().setAncestor(companyKey);
datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
```

Above query returning results specified in #1.

But not able to sort `Employee` entities by name using this query.
When I tried to add sort clause `query.addSort("name", SortDirection.ASCENDING)` it is throwing an error as follows:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: kind is required for all orders except __key__ ascending
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java:50)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper$1.convertException(DatastoreApiHelper.java:121)
```

How to sort child entities while using ancestor path in query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is considered to be a Kindless query, because you are not querying for a specific Kind (e.g. Address or Employee). You are just saying get me all Entities that have the specified ancestor. Kindless queries can only be sorted by Key (`__key__`). No other properties are supported.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#kindless_queries) states that -

> Kindless queries
>
> A query with no kind and no ancestor retrieves all of the entities of
>   an application from Cloud Datastore. Such kindless queries cannot
>   include filters or sort orders on property values. They can, however,
>   filter on entity keys and use ancestor filters. Key filters can be
>   used by specifying **key** as the property name:

You might want to look into modifying your model to store Addresses as an Embedded List into the Empoyee Entities and see if that works better.